# Show that the torque for x = b is $M_y -b\rho S$

Tags: integration, physics

> The area R on the xy-plane corresponds to a thin metal plate with the
>   area S and a constant density $\rho$. $M_y$ is the plate's moment
>   corresponding to the y-axis.
>
> a) Show that the moment corresponding to $x = b$ is $M_y - b\rho S$,
>   if the plate is right from $x = b$.
>
> b) Show that the moment corresponding to $x = b$ is $b\rho S - M_y$,
>   if the plate is left from $x = b$.

Now, I don't actually know much about physics. I assume they are talking about [this moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(physics)), but I can't be sure. I also assume the answer has something to do with the fact that $m = \rho \cdot V$, but otherwise I'm stuck.

Comment: The "moment" they are talking about is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_of_area). What is $S$ ?

Comment: S is the area of the plate, not A. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that $M_y$ is the moment corresponding to the $y$-axis (i.e., the line $x = 0$ is saying (according to the definition linked in Sou's comment) that 
$$
M_y = \iint_R x^2 \rho~dy~dx
$$
where here $\rho$ is the density, not the "distance to the axis" as it is in the linked wikipedia page.

The thing you're supposed to compute replaces $x$ (the distance from a point $(x, y)$ to the $x$ axis) with $x - b$ (the distance from $(x, y)$ to the line $x = b$), i.e., you're computing

$$
M' = \iint_R (x-b)^2 \rho~dy~dx
$$

"Where the plate is right from $x = b$" means that $x > b$ for all points $(x, y)$ of the plate; presumably this helps somehow in the simplifications you have to make.

Anyhow, do some algebra to relate $M'$ to the known value $M_y$, and see where it gets you.

Comment: So to calculate $M_y$, I first have to calculate $int_R x^2\rho dy$, right? But how can I do it, if it's x^2 inside the integral and not some function $f(y)$

Comment: No -- you DON'T need to do that. You don't have to compute $M_y$ at all; all you need to do is show how $M'$ is *related to* $M_y$ (namely, that in the first case, it is $M_y - b\rho S$).